# How to send 1 matic to users

Tags: solidity, polygon

still figuring out basics. Let's say I want to send 1 matic to an address.

I know for mainnet ethereum I would do: `addy.transfer(1 ether)`.

For matic, would it be `addy.transfer(1 matic)`?

I'm guessing not but I don't know

Answer (score 1):

I assume this code will be on a smart contract, and the smart contract will be on a specific blockchain. So yes, it's the same thing. Polygon is a blockchain that also uses the EVM (ethereum virtual machine), so the code is the same. Likewise, if you deploy to a testnet, it will transfer faulcet to someone else.